# Error in SSRS when trying to update my dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to update one of my datasets in SSRS, and I am receiving the following error

"Could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct"

My query is:

```
`SELECT eg.Name AS PropertyGroupName
, CASE ec.RAG WHEN 0 THEN 'Green' WHEN 1 THEN 'Amber' ELSE 'Red' END AS RAGColor
, CASE ec.RAG WHEN 0 THEN 'Green' WHEN 1 THEN 'Gold' ELSE 'Red' END AS RAGDisplayColor
, en.PropertyReference
, en.Name
, en.Address1
, en.Address2
, en.Address3
, en.Address4
, en.PostCode
, ec.ComplianceType AS [Compliance Type]
, ec.NextEventDate
, ec.RAG
, ec.Notes AS ComplianceDetail
FROM            tEntityCompliance AS ec 
INNER JOIN tEntity AS en ON en.ID = ec.EntityID 
INNER JOIN tEntityGroupEntity AS ege ON ege.EntityID = en.ID 
INNER JOIN tEntityGroup AS eg ON eg.ID = ege.EntityGroupID
WHERE        (ec.CompanyID = @CompanyID) 
AND (en.CompanyID = @CompanyID) 
AND (eg.CompanyID = @CompanyID) 
AND (en.Deleted = 0) 
AND (en.Status = 1) 
AND (eg.Name <> 'All properties')
AND (ec.ComplianceType IN (@ComplianceTypeFilter))
AND (eg.ID IN (@PropertyGroupNames)) 
AND (ec.RAG <> 0)'
```

Comment: Did you do what the message suggested? Verify connection and check statement syntax in Management Studio.

Comment: Is the back tick before SELECT a typo?

Comment: I have checked verified the connection and checked the syntax within my management studio. Yes sorry the back tick is a typo

Comment: All I have amended to the data set is the line - AND (ec.ComplianceType IN (@ComplianceTypeFilter))

Comment: What is in @ComplianceTypeFilter?A comma delimites string?

Comment: I guess `@ComplianceTypeFilter` is a multi-value?